# AjaxFileUpload & asyncfileupload both causing full page postback

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have googled and have search this forum, i can not find solution to my problem. As stated by the title in my webforms project using vs 2015 both these mentioned controls are causing a full page post back after uploading is done. In my other projects this works fine. But in this particular one i cant figure it out. Is there just a common thing I am over looking, I have created fresh pages with out using the master-page I still get the same results - full post back. I did not post my code because i am using the controls as any other programmer would.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="pic1.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="SSWebAppV1._1.pic1" %>
    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
    Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    </head>
    <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
   </asp:ScriptManager>
   <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
   Width="500px" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png" MaximumNumberOfFiles="4" 
   OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" />

   </div>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

****code-behind***

```
    protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, 
    AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Eimages/" + fileName));
    }
```

Comment: Can you share some code snippets for better understanding?

Comment: Please look at https://forums.asp.net/t/1518577.aspx?Prevent+full+page+refresh+during+postback

Comment: I am not using the controls in an update panel

Comment: @FaizaniRabbani updated question to include code snippet

Comment: @Arihant Jain I think the point of using theses controls is to avoid using an update panel, and secondly fileupload controls and update-panels cause a whole new scenario of new problems where you still have to do full post back is not ??

Comment: Changed the version to AjaxControlTooolKit to 17.1.1.0 still no help